# Pandas Series - easy way to add a single value and drop a specific row

Tags: pandas

**First question:** is there a simple way of adding a single value to the bottom of a series (so that it will be auto indexed)? I know `s[len(s)]=value` is not the way since there might already be an index that is equal to `len(s)` and in that case it will only update. Couldn't find an answer anywhere online.

**Second question:** Is there a simple way to delete a specific row, without testing anything about it? for example if I want to delete the 4th row, regardless of its index value (which might be anything) or its actual value.

Hope you guys can help, it will also be helpful to know there are no ways of doing those things (but I suspect there are).

Thank you

Answer (score 2):

First question: s.index[-1] to select the last value of the index

```
s.loc[s.index[-1]+1]=val
```

**Alternative:**

```
s.append(pd.Series(data=val ,index = i))
```

Second question: [`Series.drop`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.drop.html) selecting the 4th of the index

```
s.drop(s.index[3])
```

Comment: These lines doesn't seem to work as specified. they are still index based and not position based.

Comment: `o that it will be auto indexed` this depend on you r index obviously, you can't autoindex , you could use `s = s.reset_index(drop=True)` before

Comment: see alternative